# How to wrap local data reading with an API or custom file format?

Tags: data, api

Specific problem: people have saved CSV files over the last few years on a network drive. Over time, some columns have been added/modifed and some meaning of the values have changed slightly (e.g. coordinates are saved w.r.t. cropped image or w.r.t. original image, paths have moved, etc.). Working with different versions can be quite painful now.

Solution approach: The obvious reason is to version such data and not access it directly via e.g. `pd.read_csv`, but rather through a class such as `Dataset.open(csv_path)` and appropriate methods. However, this solution seems very application-centric and goes against the guideline "Data is self-describing and does not rely on an application for interpretation and meaning" from the [data-centric manifesto](http://www.datacentricmanifesto.org/). Instead, I'd prefer a solution closer to the data, e.g. data sitting behind some API or wrapping access via a custom file format. Does anybody have experience implementing such things and can recommend simple solutions?